# Offer pending for budget review

Tags: interviewing

I recently interviewed with a company. I had a great onsite interview and good experience with the company. I expected to get an offer soon after the interview. However, 4 days after interview, I was then told by the manager that they have a new VP and the new VP would like to have a budget review which will take about a month before approving new hires. Do I still have the chance to get hired? The financial situation for this company is very good. Never face this situation before. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- unfortunately this isn't the kind of question we can answer here, since it's entirely dependent on company-specific policy. It all depends on whether you can believe what the manager is telling you. Don't wait -- keep looking.

Comment: @mcknz I disagree. Whether the reason for the delay is budgetary, pending review or is the result of a reorganisation, the core question is valid: "What do I do if a job offer is being withheld due to internal company events?" Richard U's answer is a very good one for answering this core question.

Comment: @mcknz It's not company specific.  The OP is asking if an offer pending a budget review is a valid offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems

- Budget review
- Candidate review

If the new VP is that hands on to literally stop hiring for a budget review then very likely they will also review the candidates.  The new VP is likely to have different priorities.

Yes you still have a chance but keep looking.

I don't think VPs appreciate the effort of getting the right candidate.  A good candidate is not likely to be available in another 30-90 days.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you have a chance, but keep job hunting.  I've had this go either way, personally.

Treat it as if you did **NOT** get the job until you hear otherwise.  If you find something else in the mean time, take it.  An offer without a start date pending things that have nothing to do with you is no offer.  Move on, and if nothing else comes up and they get back to you take it, but don't wait for them to decide to hire you or not.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No offer letter = No job. Sorry

Comment: (Assuming this current company is their first choice no matter what) I would also say that if they do get an offer from somewhere else that it couldn't hurt telling the hiring manager at the current company that you got an offer and they may try to get the new VP to expedite that part of the review.

Comment: I have been through this, happened to be a security breach caused priorities to change from staffing for a time.  In my case, it was a position I really wanted, so I continued looking in case another position clicked, but in the end I held out until the situation cleared and it worked out.  Keep looking but also keep in touch with the company.  If you get consistent answers then you may still be OK, but until you have an offer letter in hand, don't close other doors.